# How To create a Comments list with ajax in asp.net core?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-core, razor-pages

i want to make a comments list which i want to show for example 5 comments when page loaded.
Like a dropdown list that has 5 items(comments) in it and has a button named `Load More` i want something like when the user click on `Load More` Button it sends a page an AJAX request and server responds it.

I don't know about JavaScript Programming , So I Need A Sample ( FrontEnd And Backend ).

I'm new to programming , if anyone did this thing or knows how to do it please send the example.

(I'm Using Razor pages Web Application)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a simple working demo , you could refer to:

Model

```
public class Comment
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreateTime { get; set; }
}
```

CommentList PageModel

```
public class CommentListModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SampleContext _context;

    public CommentListModel(SampleContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
    [BindProperty]
    public List<Comment> Comments { get; set; }
    public void OnGet()
    {
        Comments = _context.Comment.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreateTime).Take(5).ToList();
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetAllCommentAsync()
    {
        Comments = _context.Comment.OrderByDescending(c => c.CreateTime).ToList();
        return Partial("_CommentPartial", Comments);
    }
}
```

CommentList page,  show 5 comments when page loaded and use ajax to call `AllComment` method to return Partial view which displays the all of comment data

```
@page
@model RazorPages3_1.CommentListModel

<div id="commentlist">
<table class="table table-striped">
    @foreach (var comment in Model.Comments)
    {
        <tr>
            <td>@comment.Content</td>
            <td>@comment.CreateTime</td>
        </tr>
    }
    <tr>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="clicklink">Load more</a>
    </tr>
</table>
</div>

@section Scripts
{
 <script>
  $("#clicklink").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "get",
        url: "/CommentList?handler=AllComment",
        success: function (response) {
            $("#commentlist").html(response);
        }
    });
  });
 </script>
}
```

_CommentPartial view

```
@model List<RazorPages3_1.Models.Comment>
<table class="table table-striped">
  @foreach (var comment in Model)
  {
   <tr>
    <td>@comment.Content</td>
    <td>@comment.CreateTime</td>
   </tr>
  }
</table>
```

Result

[image]